# What extends a PHP session's lifetime

Tags: php, session

I have read the answers here [What keeps a php session alive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22904216/what-keeps-a-php-session-alive) but still have a few questions about PHP sessions.

I currently have an application and the session times out according to PHP settings.

On the other SO question, which I linked above, a user says

> What keeps the session alive is your browser sending the session id
>   (stored in a cookie) to the server, whether you use it or not.

So if my app runs on app.example.com, and I want to keep my session from timing out (without changing the PHP settings) what would I do?

Would making an ajax request to an image file stored on the same hostname work? Or would I need to make an ajax call to a PHP script that uses session_start?

Comment: what i do is (I'm using codeigniter). I put a `check` in every controller. Then in every check, `if the result true` i set new expired time

Comment: I'm not using codeigniter. I'm working with an application developed by a third party. I don't have access to all of the PHP, it's encoded.

So looking for a way using jQuery to keep the session from expiring. I am able to edit the front-end tempaltes.